# Problems with network configuration

Tags: networking

I am a beginner to the Raspberry Pi. I have connected my Raspberry Pi with an hdmi cable to desktop and I have some thing wrong with it because when I try to update I am getting these errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://raspberrypi.collabora.com/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'raspberrypi.collabora.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
```

I have changed the configuration as per this [link](http://www.modmypi.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address) but still I could not pinp google and could not solve these problems.

Comment: Please include the output of `lsusb`, `ifconf`, the contents of relevant config files (/etc/network/interfaces, /etc/dhcpcd.conf, ...). You might als want to cite the relevant part of the included link if it helps to understand the problem.

Comment: What about changing sources? You should probably do a bit more research before asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on having a USB wifi dongle plugged in - and one that you know is compatible with the Pi. I would remove anything to do with static IPs first, that is a more complex set up, just get this working first.

So, type.....

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

Which will bring up interfaces file.

Find this bit...

```
    allow-hotplug wlan0
     iface wlan0 inet dhcp
     wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
     iface default inet dhcp
```

Replace it with this....

```
    auto wlan0
     iface wlan0 inet dhcp
     wpa-ssid YOURNETWORKID
     wpa-psk YOURNETWORKPASSWORD
     iface default inet dhcp
```

Ctrl-X and Y to save and exit.

Type sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

This will restart networking.

It should now connect and you can ping google.com etc.

If it still doesn't work, make sure you have removed anything to do with static IPs.

Hope that helps.